# command similar to ' free -m' but in in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, memcached

i want to view the cached memory in (Windows vista) my operating system via cmd .
on linux, i try :
 `free -m`
 and it give me a good result.
so i want to a similar command in windows vista 
thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Windows key + R then type taskmgr hit enter and see tab Performance